# Insertion sort in C using linked list

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

I have to make a telephone directory program. The program should read names and numbers from a file. I have successfully created a linked list containing this data. Now I want to sort them alphabetically. How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your objective.

If you want to do this efficiently, stick pointers to every element into an array, and then sort the array alphabetically using an algorithm like [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (`qsort` in C); lastly, re-create the list from the sorted array.

On the other hand, if this is homework and you have to use insertion sort as the title of the post suggests, it's a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting linked lists needs an online algorithm (ie an algorithm that doesn't depend on fast random access) like insertion sort or a stack-based mergesort implementation.

If you want to insert (few) items into an already sorted list, use insertion sort. If you want to sort a complete list (or insert a large number of items), use mergesort.

An implementation of these algorithms can be found here:

- [ll_sort.h](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/raw-file/tip/ll_sort.h)
- [ll_sort.c](http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/raw-file/tip/ll_sort.c)

Please let me know if you find a bug as the code hasn't really been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sort them after you've created the linked list?

The best approach for sorting data like this may be to use a tree and create it sorted as you load the data. A tree data structure is also quick for searching, although a hash would probably be fastest. Note that strcmp is not the quickest way to sort or search. You can maintain an index into the search term and code it so that the index points to the first unmatched character. Then you only need to compare on that one character. However I don't have time to give example code for that.

```
typedef struct directory_entry_t
{
    char *name;
    char *number;
    directory_entry_t *before;
    directory_entry_t *after;
} directory_entry;

...

bool found;

while(!found)
{
    int result = strcmp("name", node->name);

    if(0 == result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Duplicate entry for %s.\n", name);
    }
    else if(0 < result)
    {
        if(NULL == node->after)
        {
             /* Create a new node, populate it, and store a pointer to it at node->after. */
             found = true;
        }
        else
        {
             node = node->after;
        }
    else
    {
        /* Like the above case, but for before. */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort is slow, but if you want to use it look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

There are many other [sorting algoritms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms), the fasted of which (T&C apply) are O(NlogN). I suggest looking at either [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Comment: quicksort needs random access for pivot selection and can't be used (efficiently) with linked lists

Comment: @Christoph Not if you settle for the first element being the pivot.

Comment: ...which will kill performance for already sorted (or partially sorted) lists

Comment: @Christoph Yes, you're quite right. But for a homework assignment which this probably is, that shouldn't matter much as long as you're aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is just about the worst data structure imaginable for sorting. If you do insertion then you have to do linear traversal across the list. Are you sure you've asked the right question?

Comment: @Christoph agreed, but my point remains, can you think of a worse data structure for sorting?

Comment: tongue-in-cheek - arrays; if your objects are large, using a list can be faster, as you only need to re-link the nodes instead of copying the data; in practice, you'd probably create an array of pointers to the objects and then sort that, but sometimes it's just less hassle to sort the list

Comment: @Christoph: I tend to program in a language which uses references to objects so an array of instances is just an array of pointers in any case. I'm also a fan of creating an array of indices and then sorting those with some indirection. This allows you to sort without modifying the master data. I must admit I don't know mergesort and I intend to read up on it because, as you say, it is suitable for linear access patterns (as opposed to random access).

Comment: you should look up (or figure out) the stack-based variant: if you naively translate a recursive or iterative mergesort for arrays to linked lists, you'll end up unnecessarily traversing the list when subdividing it; the code by Simon Tatham linked from the wikipedia page uses the iterative variant as a basis, which - in my simple tests - actually performed the worst on lists...

Answer (score 0):

```
void insertionsort(node *head,node *tail)
{
    node *temp1=head,*temp2=temp1->next;
    node *temp3;
    while(temp1->next!=NULL)
    {
    (temp1==tail)
            break;
    temp2=temp1->next;
    if(temp2->data<temp1->data)
    {
        int j;
        j=temp2->data;
        temp2->data=temp1->data;
        temp1->data=j;
        insertionsort(head,temp2);
    }
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
}
```