# C Sorting trouble

Tags: c, sorting

How do I sort the occurrence of each word in descending order?

My current code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORDLEN 50

typedef struct node_struct NODE;
struct node_struct {
  char *word;    
  int count;
  NODE *next;
};

/*compare and adds words to the list*/
NODE *new_node(char *word, NODE *head) {
  NODE *p = head;
  char *s;

  if (p == NULL) {
    p = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(word) + 1));
    strcpy(s, word);
    p->word = s;
    p->count = 1;
    p->next = head;
    return p;
  }
  for (; p->next != NULL && strcmp(p->word, word) != 0; p = p->next);
  if (strcmp(p->word, word) == 0) {
    p->count += 1;
    return head;
  }else{
    p->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p = p->next;
    s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(word) + 1));
    strcpy(s, word);
    p->count = 1;
    p->word = s;
    p->next = NULL;
    return head;
  }
}
/*gets words*/
char *getword(char *w, int n)
{
  int i = 0;
  int c;

  if (n <= 0 || feof(stdin))
    return NULL;
  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF && ! isalpha(c)) {
    c = getchar();
  }
  if (c == EOF)
    return NULL;
  while (isalpha(c)) {
    if (i < n - 1) {
      w[i] = toupper(c);
      i++;
    }
    c = getchar();
  }
  w[i] = '\0';
  return w;
}
/*print*/
void print(NODE *p) {
  for (; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
    printf("%s %d\n",p->word, p->count);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  char w[WORDLEN];
  NODE *p = NULL;
  int i;

  while (getword(w, WORDLEN) != NULL) {
 p = new_node(w, p);
  }
  print(p);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I have tried making a bubble sort, but I'm finding it difficult to get it to work with pointers.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365025/insertion-sort-in-c-using-linked-list/4367133#4367133

Comment: add your sorting code to the question and we can help you complete it and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any sorting algorithm for sorting you linked list. You can find explanation of sorting algos on wikipedia. Here are some of the most simple sort algorithms

[Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

[Insert Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_sort)

[Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

these Wikipedia pages also contain pseudo code for these algorithms so it should be pretty straight forward translating these algos into C. Your starting point is "P" in main() i.e  and you can use these algos to sort either in ascending or descending order.

Comment: the Wikipedia page for merge-sort doesn't have pseudo-code for the stack-based variant; if you adapt the presented algorithms, you'll have to needlessly re-interate the list, which kills performance; for simplicity's sake, I'd go with insertion sort instead, which is well-suited to linked lists as-is...

Comment: @Chritoph- Mergesort is very easily implemented on linked lists because the two main steps - splitting the list in half and merging two sorted lists together - can be done fairly easily.  It's also asymptotically faster than insertion sort on large data sets where the input isn't already highly sorted.

Comment: @templatetypedef: but when using the standard algorithm, splitting the list involves re-iteration and you'll no longer be in O(N log N) but O(N^2)

Comment: @Chrisoph- The recurrence relation for mergesort (T(n) <= 2T(n/2) + O(n)) allows you to make any constant number of passes over the input sequence while still getting the O(n lg n) runtime guarantee.  Adding an extra linear-time splitting step doesn't change this.  Try working the math out for T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 100n; it still comes out to O(n lg n).

Comment: @templatetypedef: you're right, I mis-counted the number of elements scanned when subdividing the list; I was open to the misconception because I remember timing different implementations of mergesort, and coming up with times comparable to insertion sort when using the stanard algorithm; I'll check if I can dig up the code to see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague -- do you want to learn something about sorting functions or do you just want the program to work? :-)

In case you just want something that works, you could consider using a dynamically expanding array instead of a linked list. That way you can realloc() when adding new entries, and sort with normal qsort()

As a side effect, you might also see less memory fragmentation compared to using a linked list which could have nice effects on the overall performance - especially if you do fewer and larger re-allocations. The code will also be more compact which could improve readability.

Update: Ah, I can't resist showing what I mean. If you use a dynamically expanding array, the function new_node could be implemented like this:

```
NODE * nodes = NULL;
unsigned node_count = 0;

void new_node(char word) {
    unsigned n;

    for (n = 0; n < node_count && strcmp(nodes[n], word) != 0; n++);

    if (n < node_count) {
        nodes[n].count++;
    } else {
        nodes = realloc(nodes, sizeof(NODE) * node_count + 1);
        assert(nodes != NULL);
        nodes[n].word = strdup(word);
        assert(nodes[n].word != NULL);
        nodes[n].count = 1;
    }
}
```

If you *like* this or not is a matter of personal preference. If this is *usable* or not really depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it thanks everyone for your help!

my code is now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORDLEN 50

typedef struct node_struct NODE;
struct node_struct {
  char *word;    
  int count;
  NODE *next;
};

void new_node(char *word, NODE **head);
void print(NODE *p);
void mergesort_node(NODE **head);
void split_list(NODE *source, NODE **p, NODE **q);
NODE *merge_sorted_lists(NODE *source1, NODE *source2);
char *getword(char *word);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char w[WORDLEN];
  NODE *p = NULL;

  while (getword(w)) {
    new_node(w, &p);
  }
  mergesort_node(&p);
  print(p);
    return 0;
  }

//adds words to the list
void new_node(char *word, NODE **head) {
  NODE *p = *head;
  char *s;

  if (p == NULL) {
    p = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(word) + 1));
    strcpy(s, word);
    p->word = s;
    p->count = 1;
    p->next = NULL;
    *head = p;
  }else{
  for (; p->next != NULL && strcmp(p->word, word) != 0; p = p->next);
  if (strcmp(p->word, word) == 0) {
    p->count += 1;
  }else{
    p->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    p = p->next;
    s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(word) + 1));
    strcpy(s, word);
    p->count = 1;
    p->word = s;
    p->next = NULL;
  }
  }
}
//gets words
char *getword(char *w)
{
  int i = 0;
  int c;

  if (WORDLEN <= 0 || feof(stdin)){
    return NULL;}
  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF && ! isalpha(c)) {
    c = getchar();
  }
  if (c == EOF)
    return NULL;
  while (isalpha(c)) {
    if (i < WORDLEN  - 1) {
      w[i] = toupper(c);
      i++;
    }
    c = getchar();
  }
  w[i] = '\0';
  return w;
}
//print
void print(NODE *p) {
  for (; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
    printf("%s %d\n",p->word, p->count);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

//mergesort

void mergesort_node(NODE **head) {
  NODE *p, *q, *newhead;
  newhead = *head;

  if (newhead == NULL || newhead->next == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  split_list(newhead, &p, &q);
  mergesort_node(&p);
  mergesort_node(&q);
  *head = merge_sorted_lists(p, q);
}

//Splits list in middle, using fast/slow method
void split_list(NODE *source, NODE **p, NODE **q) {
  NODE *f, *s;
  s = source;
  f = source->next;

  while (f != NULL) {
    f = f->next;
    if (f != NULL) {
      s = s->next;
      f = f->next;
    }
  }
  *p = source;
  *q = s->next;
  s->next = NULL;
}

//Merges two individually sorted lists into one sorted list.
NODE *merge_sorted_lists(NODE *source1, NODE *source2) {
  NODE *p, *q, *e, *newhead;
  p = source1;
  q = source2;
  e = newhead = NULL;

  while (p != NULL && q != NULL) { 
    if (p->count >= q->count) {      //Compares the top items from the lists,
      if (e == NULL) {               //and puts the largest as next in the new list.
    e = p;
    newhead = e;
      }else{
    e->next = p;
    e = e->next;
      }
      p = p->next;
    }else if (p->count < q->count) {
      if (e == NULL) {
    e = q;
    newhead = e;
      }else{
    e->next = q;
    e = e->next;
      }
      q = q->next;
    }
  }
  if (p == NULL) {     //If one list ends, the rest of the other is added to the new list.
    if (e == NULL) {
      e = q;
      newhead = e;
    }else{
      e->next = q;
    }
  }else if (q == NULL) {
    if (e == NULL) {
      e = p;
      newhead = e;
    }else{
      e->next = p;
    }
  }
  return newhead;
}
```